# escape specific characters in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, replace

I have a string like this :

```
var str = "[{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"I have below information for you:\"}, {\"type\": \"table\", \"columns\": [\"Product Name\", \"Status\", \"Comments\"], \"rows\": [[\"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"send('Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon ')\">Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon</button>\", \"Confirmed\", \"Your order has been verified and you will receive updates when dispatched from our warehouse\"]]}]";
```

I want to replace all \"button\" with \\"button\\" , \"send with \\"send and )\" with )\\"

What I tried so far : 
 case 1 : to replace \"button\" with \\"button\\" :

```js
var str = "[{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"I have below information for you:\"}, {\"type\": \"table\", \"columns\": [\"Product Name\", \"Status\", \"Comments\"], \"rows\": [[\"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"send('Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon ')\">Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon</button>\", \"Confirmed\", \"Your order has been verified and you will receive updates when dispatched from our warehouse\"]]}]";

var a = str.replace(/\"button\"/g, '\\\"button\\\"');

console.log(a)
```

This gives the output as

```
[{"type": "text", "text": "I have below information for you:"}, {"type": "table", "columns": ["Product Name", "Status", "Comments"], "rows": [["<button type=\"button\" onclick="send('Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon ')">Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon</button>", "Confirmed", "Your order has been verified and you will receive updates when dispatched from our warehouse"]]}]
```

The above output has type=\"button\" hence JSON.parse will work in this.

case 2 : to replace \"send with \\"send

```js
var str = "[{\"type\": \"text\", \"text\": \"I have below information for you:\"}, {\"type\": \"table\", \"columns\": [\"Product Name\", \"Status\", \"Comments\"], \"rows\": [[\"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"send('Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon ')\">Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon</button>\", \"Confirmed\", \"Your order has been verified and you will receive updates when dispatched from our warehouse\"]]}]";

var a = str.replace(/\"button\"/g, '\\\"button\\\"');
var a = str.replace(/\"send"/g, '\\\"send');

console.log(a)
```

This gives the output :

```
[{"type": "text", "text": "I have below information for you:"}, {"type": "table", "columns": ["Product Name", "Status", "Comments"], "rows": [["<button type="button" onclick="send('Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon ')">Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon</button>", "Confirmed", "Your order has been verified and you will receive updates when dispatched from our warehouse"]]}]
```

The above output doesnt even contain type=\"button\" or \"send . It removed the escape character. So JSON.parse will throw an error.

case 3 : when trying to replace )\" with )\\"

```
var a = str.replace(/)\"/g, ')\\\"');
```

This throws an error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /)\"/: Unmatched ')'`

The expected final output is :

```
[{"type": "text", "text": "I have below information for you:"}, {"type": "table", "columns": ["Product Name", "Status", "Comments"], "rows": [["<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"send('Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon ')\">Enfance Flower Detailed Sleeveless Rosette Dress - Maroon</button>", "Confirmed", "Your order has been verified and you will receive updates when dispatched from our warehouse"]]}]
```

This final output will contain escaped double quotes inside of a string such that it will work with JSON.parse.

How do I do this?

Note: I had put three slashes but I have no idea why one of the slash is removed automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to replace `button` and `send` without taking into account the slash before and you should get the result you want:

```
var a = str.replace('"button"', '\\\"button"').replace('"send', '\\\"send');
```

Comment: btw this only replaces the first occurence. How to replace all the occurences?

Comment: btw this only replaces the first occurence. How to replace all the occurences?

Comment: No problem! Just add the global modifier to replace all the occurences (add `'g'` parameter to `str.replace`).

Comment: is this correct str.replace('"button"'g, '\\\"button"') ?

Comment: No, because you're not using the RegExp syntax, you should do `str.replace('"button"', '\\\"button"', 'g')` :)

Comment: this is only replacing the trailing " for the first occurence only

Comment: ok, sorry, it's apparently non standard. Then you should use `str.replace(new RegExp('"button"', 'g'), '\\\"button"')`.

Comment: Thanks. Working now